# '[CLPlacemark]?' is not convertible to '[CLPlacemark]' -> swift2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

this is a part of code I found on StackOverflow.
It was working in Swift 1.2
Why this code is not working anymore in swift 2:

```
geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        let placeArray = placemarks as [CLPlacemark] // !!! ERROR HERE !!!

        // Place details
        var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
        placeMark = placeArray[0]

        // Address dictionary
        print(placeMark.addressDictionary)

        // Location name
        if let locationName = placeMark.addressDictionary["Name"] as? NSString {
            print(locationName)
        }

        // Street address
        if let street = placeMark.addressDictionary["Thoroughfare"] as? NSString {
            print(street)
        }

        // City
        if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary["City"] as? NSString {
            print(city)
        }

        // Zip code
        if let zip = placeMark.addressDictionary["ZIP"] as? NSString {
            print(zip)
        }

        // Country
        if let country = placeMark.addressDictionary["Country"] as? NSString {
            print(country)
        }

    })
```

Error is GetLocationViewController.swift:67:41: `'[CLPlacemark]?' is not convertible to '[CLPlacemark]'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to unwrap the placemarks array (implicitly or optional chaining) before assigning it to a type of [CLPlacemarks]

For your example, you should use optional chaining so

```
if let validPlacemark = placemarks?[0]{
     let placemark = validPlacemark as? CLPlacemark;
}
```

Than place all your logic inside the braces so if it finds a valid placemark array, it will execute your desired commands. If not, it will do nothing or you can handle it however you please

Comment: Still return an error.  Cannot subscript a value of type '[CLPlacemark]?' with an index of type 'Int'

Comment: Still not working :/  'CLPlacemark?' is not convertible to 'CLPlacemark'

Comment: Now a Warning      "Forced cast from 'CLPlacemark' to 'CLPlacemark' always succeeds; did you mean to use 'as'?"       Look like better but Warning are futur error :)

Comment: yes!! sorry about that, didn't have playground in front of me to test it out real quick

Comment: So what should I do ? In order to remove this Warning :)

Comment: Is my new edit working ? You could use as? instead and check for nil to make sure it unwrapped or i prefer to just use optional chaining.

Comment: Still not :/  "Conditional cast from 'CLPlacemark' to 'CLPlacemark' always succeeds"

Comment: Now "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CLPlacemark'"

Comment: darn, I should just revert to the version that was working earlier.

Comment: @VivienG use the code I edited; while it is not approved (350 rep to go), here it is: `if let validPlacemark = placemarks?[0]{

     // use validPlacemark

}`

Answer (score 0):

placemarks is not guaranteed to have a value, you could do this:

```
let placeArray: [CLPlacemark] = placemarks as? [CLPlacemark] ?? []
```

Which reads as,

if `placemarks` can be casted as `[CLPlacemark]`, then do so.  Otherwise, assign an empty array.

Here's this code in practice:

[image]

I'm realizing now that you're on Xcode 7!  It's even easier there, all you need is this:

```
let placeArray = placemarks ?? []
```

Comment: This still return an error.  Downcast from '[CLPlacemark]?' to '[CLPlacemark]' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Comment: @VivienG - I just realized that you were on the new beta!  See the bottom update, you can do it even easier since Objective-C generics have been updated for array types!

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7.0, Objective-C has generic arrays, so your `placemarks` array is no longer `[AnyObject]?` but is now `[CLLocation]?`. You don't need to cast the array, you can just unwrap the optional. With the addition of guard statements, your completion block is now as simple as:

```
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
    guard let placemarks = placemarks else { print(error); return; }
    guard let placemark = placemarks.first else { return; }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let pm = placemarks?[0]{
     // Example: get the country
     print("Your country: \(pm.country!)")
}
```