# Swift 2 , CLGeocoder() and placemarks

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, clgeocoder

I want to get the address of the GPS signal and I write that code: `

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {


            print("Κάτι δεν πήγε καλά με το GPS!")

        } else {

            if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks?[0] as! CLPlacemark) {

                print(p)

            }

        }
```

The error is that: Downcast from 'CLPlacemark?' to 'CLPlacemark' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'? . Where do I have the error?

Comment: The error is in line 5 (if let p = ...)

Answer (score 0):

No need to initialize a CLPlacemark like this. This async method returns an array of CLPlacemarks and this array is optional. So you need to unwrap the array if it exists and return the first element of that array which is already a CLPlacemark.

```
if let validPlacemark = placemarks?[0]{
 print(validPlacemark)
}
```

['[CLPlacemark]?' is not convertible to '[CLPlacemark]' -> swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923810/clplacemark-is-not-convertible-to-clplacemark-swift2/30924267#30924267)

Comment: I did it but now the error is this: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CLPlacemark' .

Comment: Awesome glad I could help